# GGplot using continues color for Points but discrete for text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a problem where i want to make a geom_point graph and have the points change color depending on the variable points. But i want a text box next to it saying if they were chosen in either red or green.

I tried the following code.

```
    ggplot(dataset2, aes(x = x_value, y = y_value, size = Points)) +
    geom_text_repel(aes(label = Name, color = Chosen), size = 5) +
    geom_point(aes(color = as.numeric(Student_votes))) +  
    scale_color_continuous(name = "Points") +
    theme_bw()
```

This gives the error Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

here is a dataset to show what I would like

```
dataset2 <- data.frame(
  x_value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  y_value = c(10, 15, 8, 12, 20),
  Points = c(50, 30, 45, 60, 40),
  Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  Chosen = c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes"),
  Student_votes = c(15, 20, 10, 25, 18))
```

So points can change depending on value of points but Chosen should be Green for yes and red for no.

Is this possible?

Comment: `dataset2$Chosen` is strings, so using `color=Chosen` is going to break with `scale_color_continuous`. Also, it's non-standard (often _wrong_) to have different `aes(color=)` expressions in the same ggplot2, unless you are using a ggplot extension such as `ggnewscale` to augment color/fill scales. (_As I'm typing this, AllanCameron answered using `ggnewscale` ..._)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `ggnewscale` package:

```r
library(ggrepel)
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot(dataset2, aes(x = x_value, y = y_value, size = Points)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = as.numeric(Student_votes))) +  
  scale_color_continuous(name = "Points") +
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = Name, color = Chosen), size = 5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red3", "green4")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

However, if I may make a suggestion, having multiple legends makes a plot difficult to read "at a glance", and direct labelling might be better here.

```r
ggplot(dataset2, aes(x = x_value, y = y_value)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(Chosen, c("Yes", "No")), alpha = Points), 
             size = 9) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Name), nudge_y = 1.25, fontface = 2) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Points), color = "white", fontface = 2) +  
  scale_color_manual(NULL, values = c("green4", "red4"),
                     labels = c("Chosen", "Not Chosen")) +
  scale_alpha(range = c(0.5, 1), guide = "none") +
  ylim(c(0, 22)) +
  labs(title = "Points chosen according to y value and score",
       subtitle = "Score is shown inside each point") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = 3))
```

[image]

To my eye, this plot is more attractive and informative. It also does not require any packages other than `ggplot2`.

Comment: Worked great! Many thanks. Also very good improvement suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using `ggnewscale` is to change the `shape=` of your points to be `21`, which allows a `fill=` component as well, and switch the aesthetics.

```r
ggplot(dataset2, aes(x = x_value, y = y_value, size = Points)) +
    geom_point(aes(fill = as.numeric(Student_votes)), shape = 21) +  
    scale_fill_continuous(name = "Points") +
    geom_text_repel(aes(label = Name, color = Chosen), size = 5) +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Two notable differences:

1. The points have a black boundary. We can use `color="transparent"` for this.
2. The hollow `Points` legend. We can use `guide(..., override.aes=..)` for this.

```r
ggplot(dataset2, aes(x = x_value, y = y_value, size = Points)) +
    geom_point(aes(fill = as.numeric(Student_votes)), color = "transparent", shape = 21) +  
    scale_fill_continuous(name = "Points") +
    geom_text_repel(aes(label = Name, color = Chosen), size = 5) +
    theme_bw() +
    guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill="black")))
```

[image]